# Comparing two file contents in java and save it another file

Tags: java

this is my code, im trying to compare two .csv files and match them and save the common pain in another file. How do i do it?
This is the cotnent of item_no.csv file

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

This is the content of item_desc.csv file

```
1,chocolate,100
2,biscuit,20
3,candy,10
4,lollipop,5
5,colddrink,50
6,sandwitch,70
```

**EDIT** This is the expected output:

```
1,chocolate,100
2,biscuit,20
3,candy,10
4,lollipop,5
5,colddrink,50
```

This is my code:

```
   package fuu;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;

    import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;

    public class Demo {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/yotta/eclipse/workspace/Test/WebContent/doc/item_no.csv"));
     BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/yotta/eclipse/workspace/Test/WebContent/doc/item_desc.csv"));
     String line =  null;
     String line1 =  null;
     String line2 = null;
     String[] str=null;
     String[] str1=null;
     try {
       while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        str = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(str[0]);             
      }  




       while((line1 = br1.readLine())!=null){
         str1 = line1.split(",");
         System.out.println(str1[0]+" "+str1[1]+" "+str1[2]);

       }


       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
       }
```

Comment: you didn't mention where is the problem?!

Comment: @Messi: what is the expected output?

Comment: What do you expect to obtain?

Comment: Well, somehow your code misses the most important part: the comparison. And since your description about that is very vague, it is hard to help you there.

Comment: In order to make this post more straightforward, I have added expected output, based on my guess. OP, please review and edit if that's not the expected output.

Comment: @bpgergo Since this your edit is based on your own guess, it is not helpful at all. It just tricks other readers to think that this the *real* expected output. You should consider deleting it.

Comment: Guy's thanks for ur feeds..

Comment: @hasan83, the trouble is, i'm not able to figure out how to do the comparison b/w the two files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the different steps.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> descMap = new HashMap<>();
        String line;
        // read all item descriptions
        try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("item_desc.csv"))) {
            while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                int itemNbrSeparator = line.indexOf(',');
                String itemNbr = line.substring(0, itemNbrSeparator);
                descMap.put(itemNbr, line);
            }
        }
        List<String> matched = new ArrayList<>();
        // read the item numbers and store each matched
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("item_no.csv"))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (descMap.containsKey(line)) {
                    System.out.println(descMap.get(line));
                    matched.add(descMap.get(line));
                }
            }
        }
        // output all matched
        Path outFile = Paths.get("item_match.csv");
        Files.write(outFile, matched, Charset.defaultCharset(), new LinkOption[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is this

```
    List<String> lines1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str = line.split(",");
            lines1.add(line);
            System.out.println(str[0]);
        }

    List<String> lines2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
       str = line.split(",");
       System.out.println(str[0]);
       if(lines1.contains(str[0])){
            lines2.add(line);
       }
    }

    for (String l : lines1) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Comment: Was quite helpfull.. Thanks